# Why should I store a JWT refresh token server-side?

Tags: authentication, jwt, refresh-token

I've read several articles (such as [this](https://valor-software.com/articles/json-web-token-authorization-with-access-and-refresh-tokens-in-angular-application-with-node-js-server.html) and [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi9u53qh8LvAhXYiFwKHdmnCeUQtwIwAHoECAIQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.to%2Fjacobsngoodwin%2F12-store-refresh-tokens-in-redis-1k5d&usg=AOvVaw3o6hRGUWqIY7R3k70uxd1U), and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204367/why-should-refresh-tokens-be-saved-in-the-server-side)) that suggest storing refresh tokens server-side in a database, or in-memory (or an in-memory store, such as Redis). From what I understand this is so they can be revoked.

Is there a good reason for storing all tokens as these articles suggest, rather than just storing blacklisted tokens on logout? If I understand the reasons for storing tokens, surely I could achieve the same effect by storing a token id in Redis (with a TTL as long as the expiry, so that the table doesn't grow unweildy).

Are there downsides to this approach, and if so, what are they (or conversely, what are the upsides of storing all tokens, vs just a list of revoked tokens?)

---

To elaborate, and why I think it should be fine to have a revocation list, here's the process I am imagining:

- Issue tokens out
- Once revoked (say, on logout), add an entry to a blacklist for a unique id (say, `public_user_id` if there are many tokens for different devices) with the revocation time, and add a TTL until the token's expiry
- When a token is provided for auth, when there is an existing blacklist entry:

  - if a valid token is used, it'll be before it's expiry and have a creation time after the blacklist entry creation time for the unique id
  - if an invalid token is used, it'll either be expired or within the blacklist with the unique identifier before the entry creation

Am I missing something critical in that flow that would require a list of all tokens instead?

Comment: The only difference is, that you will save every refresh token in a blacklist after refreshing. Instead of changing a revoked boolean.

Comment: Why would I save every token? I'd only save the ones that have been revoked in that strategy

Comment: Also note that I wouldn't save expired tokens - that's covered by the first check for expiry so not every token would be saved unless every token was revoked. Which I'd probably do by invalidating the secret, not every token

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I don't understand how there's any difference revoking either token. If I know both tokens contain the claim of a user id, and they both have a time of issuance, it doesn't matter which token is presented. I can use the respective secret to decode the token, get the id from the claims, and check if there's a revocation entry with a revocation time before the token's issuance. If that's the case, the token is revoked

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Oh wait! I get what you're saying now. How do I revoke a refresh token after use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of having a list of all issued tokens is that you can have a full view of who has been already authenticated and has currently access to the system. You can then choose to revoke some tokens from this list based on any criteria (e.g. the age of the token, the roles associated with the user of the token, the IP address ranges).

If you only have a list of revoked tokens, it would be impossible to choose at runtime, an arbitrary criteria, to revoke a subset of the valid tokens. Stated otherwise, if you don't have a list of all issued tokens, the revocation criteria cannot be enforced globally at once, but only when a token is presented to a resource server.

Comment: Why is it much more difficult? I could just have a list of unique identifiers that are within each token, and the time at which revocation had been issued. If their token is less than that time, that token is invalid. Or am I missing something critical?

Comment: I've added the strategy outline to the question. Let me know if that helps understand my thought process and if there's any holes in that reasoning

Comment: Okay that does makes sense but only with your caveat of arbitrary criteria. I think in my specific case I can get away with not having a list of all tokens, as I only need to invalidate users based on a strategy where the token is scoped (that is, all tokens contain an id that I can invalidate against, so I don't need the token to invalidate it)

Answer (score 1):

The only deciding factor I can think of, that will require a list of all refresh tokens is the following:

Do you / will you, at any point, need to have a functionality where you can  dynamically revoke valid refresh tokens, based on some arbitrary, regulatory, legal, integrity, security etc. criteria?

If so, the least you will need is a list of all issued tokens, plus any metadata required to implement the criteria logic.

**Example**: "Due to regulation, I need to ban all EU users" equates to `delete from refresh_tokens were user_ip in <... eu logic ...>`

Answer (score 0):

I would aim for a direction of technical simplicity here, since the Authorization Server (AS) should do the hard work for you. Here are some end to end notes which explain some tricky aspects and suggest a simple direction.

**1. TOKEN ISSUING**

The user authenticates (and optionally consents) resulting in a token 'grant'. The AS should then store refresh tokens for you, in a database table that might be named 'delegations'. Typically the stored 'token' will be a hash rather than the real value, and will be linked to the application (client_id) and user (subject). Tokens issued might have these lifetimes:

- Refresh token: 4 hours
- Access token: 30 minutes

**2. TOKEN REFRESH**

OAuth clients such as mobile apps will silently renew access tokens during the lifetime of the grant or 'user session'. This involves sending a refresh token to the AS and getting back a new access token. For this to work the AS needs to store a hash of the refresh token in order to be able to validate the input.

**3. DEFAULT REMOVAL BEHAVIOUR**

When a user logs out, tokens are cleared from the client app, so they are gone. Newer [OAuth 2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-parecki-oauth-v2-1-02.html#name-refreshing-an-access-token) recommendations are to use rotating refresh tokens, where each access token refresh also renews the refresh token and invalidates the previous one. In our example this now means that the lifetime of a stolen refresh token is likely to be reduced - perhaps to only 30 minutes.

**4. MANUAL REVOCATION BY ADMINISTRATOR**

If for some reason you want to explicitly deny access to a particular user and application, an administrator could use the AS database and issue a command like this, though the Admin UI may provide more visual options.

- delete from delegations where client_id=[value] and subject=[value]

Whether manual revocation is likely to be manageable at a people level is questionable but it is a good capability to have, eg in security reviews.

**5. REVOCATION OF REFRESH TOKENS ON LOGOUT**

Of course the client can revoke its own refresh tokens on logout if required, before clearing tokens. This should also ensure that any access tokens for the same grant are rejected by the Authorization Server.

**6. ACCESS TOKEN VALIDITY**

Access tokens are most commonly JWTs. Revocation or logout may occur when the JWT still has 25 minutes to live. If an attacker has somehow intercepted an access token (which shouldn't usually be possible) they can continue to use it against your APIs - during this period the AS will never see the access token.

**7. API GATEWAY SETUPS**

In a more sophisticated setup, opaque access tokens are issued to internet clients, then sent to an API gateway, which introspects them, as in the [Phantom Token Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/). The gateway also maintains a cache of the access token result.

At the time of revocation the AS can raise a [Custom Event](https://curity.io/resources/learn/cloudflare-token-publisher/) to inform the API Gateway, which can then clear any cached access tokens for the user. This should ensure that the very next request with an access token for the revoked (or logged out) user is rejected.

**SUMMARY**

Unless you are dealing with a very high security domain I would aim for simplicity and follow these two principles:

- Leave token storage and revocation to the Authorization Server
- Keep tokens short lived so that revocation becomes less of an issue

Comment: Hey Gary, some great advice here about authorization servers. Pertinent to the question, I'm not sure if you're suggesting that I should or shouldn't store every token though. Are you suggesting I hash and store every refresh token?

Comment: If you are using an AS (good) then you should not need to do anything. If you are writing your own code to issue tokens (bad), AND you have clients that will be renewing access tokens with refresh tokens, then yes, hash and store them. If you can update your question with a bit more info on what back end components there are and what UIs or other clients call them, then I can maybe make other recommendations. The answer is often very much about clients rather than what the back end is doing.

Comment: Why would it be bad to write my own implementation? From what I've seen the task is as simple as issuing a token with a complex secret. Or am I very naive :p

Comment: Because you may need to handle Authorization Code Grant messages, Refresh Token Grant messages, issue scopes and claims, validate those requested against the delegation, perform auditing and so on. Therefore most people outsource all of this to a system written by experts.

Comment: But if your requirements are simpler - eg you are writing your own simple client and service, and security is not a key concern, it might not be too bad. It is worth being aware though that you can use free Authorization Severs that will do a lot of the complex stuff for you. If it is not important now then maybe bear it in mind for future projects.

Comment: Amazing! I've only used basic auth (e.g., sessions, bcrypt, salting, handling simple security concerns with helmet or equivalent) for apps where I'm not very security conscious. What are your recommendations for when to move onto an AS, and any recommendations of services? And are there any immediate vulnerabilities to that simple approach?

Comment: For most software companies the OAuth approach provides the best overall options, but there is a learning curve. For your own learning, start with a free cloud option and learn how to integrate with its endpoints, as in [My Tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/). But do things gradually and agree a direction with stakeholders if applicable.